# How to parse JSON item that has {} and String with Moshi

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

For example i have this JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "title": "Hello"
  },
  {
    "title": {}
  },
]
```

Notice that both titles have different data types, when i'm trying to parse it with `String?` it gives error:

```
com.squareup.moshi.JsonDataException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $[0].title
```

I know that this is a bad practice to use both `{}` and `String` like that in the API, but unfortunately i don't have access to the API's code.

Comment: I don't think you can parse both of your objects with the same model (because they are not the same). One has a `title` of type `string` and the other one has a `title` of type `object`.

Comment: @OhhhThatVarun i'm currently using a workaround, first assign it with `Any` then cast it manually to `String` like this `val newTitle = try { (title) as String } catch (e: Exception) { "" }`

Comment: That's the only way around it using `Any`. On other hand you can write a Custom deserializer for it this way you can handle the parsing and casting stuff on network Layer only .

Comment: As @ADM mentioned - Custom Type Adapters (deserializers) are the Moshi idiomatic way to solve this: https://github.com/square/moshi#custom-type-adapters

Comment: Can you help me to create the custom adapter?

Comment: Take a look at [Moshi's example recipes](https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes). [`MultipleFormats.java`](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/recipes/MultipleFormats.java) seems to solve a similar case to yours.